# Problem with Apache - not starting?

Tags: apache2, php

I was trying to install ion cube,

I was looking at an instruction online, and just copying  and pasting commands to Putty

I realized that I was trying to install a 32 bit version on my 64 bit machine, after getting a error message.

[The web page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ioncube-loader) that I used for instructions:

So I deleted every file from the 32 bit install and then started to install the 64 bit version.

I had finished all the steps but now when I needed to restart Apache (sudo service apache2 restart) its giving me the following error:

```
The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. 
Please read the log files to discover problems
```

The log file:

### Log File

```
! [Sat Jul 26 14:31:16.494256 2014] [:error] [pid 8725] [client 91.188.124.225:45757] script '/var/www/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Jul 26 14:31:16.494479 2014] [:error] [pid 32220] [client 91.188.124.225:33664] script '/var/www/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sat Jul 26 16:03:39.391579 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15284] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jul 26 16:03:40.473381 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14582] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 26 16:03:40.473436 2014] [core:notice] [pid 14582] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Sat Jul 26 16:31:41.212169 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14582] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Why do you even need IonCube?

Comment: To set up box billing. at this point I just want to restore it as it was.

Comment: It seems that `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` doesn't exists. Did you copy it from `/var/www/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` as indicated in your instructions? Another point: check if your zend_exention appears before zend section in your php.ini file.